# Express - Unable to Connect to MongoDB Server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I've been developing a simple web app using MongoDB, Express and NodeJS. As of yesterday, I can't seem to connect to MongoDB and keep getting the following error on the terminal:

> (node:28265) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [Mon
>   goNetworkError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND localhost localhost:27017]
>
> > at Pool. (/Users/Mendis/Desktop/UMISC_Website/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:564:11)
> >
> > at Pool.emit (events.js:182:13)
> >         at Connection. (/Users/Mendis/Desktop/UMISC_Website/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/pool.js:317:12)
> >
> > at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
> >
> > at Connection.emit (events.js:182:13)
> >
> > at Socket. (/Users/Mendis/Desktop/UMISC_Website/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:246:50)
> >
> > at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
> >
> > at Socket.emit (events.js:182:13)
> >
> > at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:82:8)
> >
> > at emitErrorAndCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:50:3)
> >
> > at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:63:19)
>
> (node:28265) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an asy
>   nc function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
>
> (node:28265) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are no
>   t handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Here is a snippet from my app.js file up until the mongoDB connection:

```
/*=========================package/schema imports=============================*/

var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose"),
    methodOverride        = require("method-override"),
    localStrategy         = require("passport-local"),
    bodyParser            = require("body-parser"),
    nodemailer            = require("nodemailer"),
    passport              = require("passport"),
    mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
    express               = require("express"),
    seedDB                = require("./seeds"),
    app                   = express();

var Event = require("./models/event"),
    User  = require("./models/user");

/*==================================app config================================*/

// connect to umisc database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/umisc", {useNewUrlParser: true});
```

Since I'm fairly new to backend development, I'm really unsure of what I've done wrong...

Comment: it might be that your mongo instance is not running

Comment: @Kieper I already verified that it's running by using mongo on the terminal. The error shows up only when I run `node app.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are getting is because you have an exception that you do not catch and bubbles up and crashes your instance for security reasons. The issue you are having is most likely due to not being able to connect to the mongo instance.

Try catching the error for a start:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://xxxxxxx.xxxx', function(err, db) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('Unable to connect to the server. Please start the server. Error:', err);
    } else {
        console.log('Connected to Server successfully!');
    }
});
```

Update: If the local connection fails then try using 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost. Sometimes issues may arise when the local hostname has been changed.

Comment: I did that and got the same error (prefixed by the console.log message)...
It's pretty confusing because I ran ./mongod on another terminal window and it says `2019-01-04T00:32:35.288+0530 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] waiting for connections on port 27017`

Comment: Try specifying: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017

Comment: Are you running both locally on your machine or are you using docker-containers etc?

Comment: That worked- Thanks!!
Also, I'm not sure what docker-containers are tbh. I'm running via the terminal on my mac.

Comment: Cool, glad to help. I updated first answer, would appreciate a vote/resolve if it fixed your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
const express = require('express');
const app =express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/newTodos', {useNewUrlParser: true});
```